# ValueError: signal only works in main thread when running streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, streamlit

I have an index.py file for displaying my dashboard (with dash and matplotlib), i'm using python 3.7.10, and i'm trying to run in on ec2 in amazon while connecting it to my github folder. i tried to run on my terminal the following:

- chmod 400 web04-test.pem
- ssh -i "web04-test.pem" ec2-user@ec2-43-206-106-106.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
- sudo su
- yum update
- yum install git
- git clone https://github.com/*****/web04-test.git
- cd web04-test
- python3 -m pip install dash
- python3 -m pip install pandas
- python3 -m pip install matplotlib
- python3 -m pip install streamlit
- python3 -m pip install networkx
- python3 -m streamlit run index.py

and when im running it, it opens an index - Streamlit browzer with this error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 563, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/ec2-user/web04-test/index.py", line 422, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 2133, in run_server
    self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1980, in run
    self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1188, in run
    run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1095, in run_simple
    reloader_type=reloader_type,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 427, in run_with_reloader
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
```

my index.py file:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input , Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import datetime

...
app = dash.Dash(__name__ )
app.layout = html.Div([...])
...
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

How can I fix it and see my dashboard?

I really appreciate any help! :)